# How to write Czech letters on Ubuntu Touch with hardware keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, ubuntu-touch, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I would like to write Czech texts on Ubuntu Touch with a hardware keyboard. I have set the hardware keyboard layout to "České (QWERTY)", however I can't write some Czech letters such as "ó" or "ď", which are not on the standard keyboard and they have to be written by pressing "´" or "ˇ" key first and than writing the corresponding letter. I have noticed that there is a special keyboard layout writing only letters with diacritical marks. Could I change between these two layouts by some keyboard shortcut or is there any other way how to write required letters?

Answer (score 3):

You want to define a compose key. I use Caps Lock for that.

In preferences, go to

> Keyboard » Shortcut » Typing

and change the Compose Key entry with any key you'd like. I suggest Caps Lock unless you use it often to write in capitals?

Once that is setup you do:

```
Compose Key + < + C → Č

Compose Key + ' + o → ó

Compose Key + ' + e → é
```

In most cases, the order in which you enter the characters does not matter. So `' + o` or `o + '` gives you the same thing. However `< + -` gives you an arrow ← and `- + <` gives you nothing...

If you have a hard time finding the combo keys to generate this or that, you may check out my reference about the [X11 Compose Key](http://linux.m2osw.com/compose-key-under-linux).